# R error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Tags: r

I'm new to R and full disclosure this is a homework assignment.  Although the problem is outside of the scope of my assignment. I have some random medical data with a lot of NA's and outliers. I wanted to select all the values of 8 or higher in the Children column that corresponds to people under the age of 60 and replace them with an NA value. I used this code and it does work even if it's not pretty:

```
x = md$Children 
y = md$Age 
md$Children[which(x >= 8 & y < 60)] = is.na(x)
```

But when I run it I get the

> Warning message:
> In md$Children[which(x >= 8 & y < 60)] = is.na(x) :
> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length.

I know I have fewer replacements than there are rows in my data but is there a way to do this better or does the warning just not matter?

Comment: is.na() returns TRUE or FALSE. This is not the value NA which is what you want to assign. See ?is.na()

Comment: It would help a lot if you supplied working example even if that example throws an error.

Comment: I don't know how to do that I signed up for this site to ask this question, I don't even think I can mark this as an answered question. This was about 200 lines of code into my project and a little bit of a rabbit hole for me.  I'm attending WGU and it's basically all self-study outside of a book that doesn't go into a lot of detail.  Thank you for your explanation about what was wrong with using is.na().

Comment: md <- data.frame(children = 6:9,age = 61:58) is a concise data frame example.  It allows a contributor to have an instannt working script rather than having to work out their own data which may or may not reflect your own. As well, I should add that intermediate assignments--here x and y--give you much more to think about and keep track of while clouding what you're doing at the same time.  Worse, it can mess up your environment with confusing variables. Lastly, learning R is a never ending, but very happy journey. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
md$Children[which(x >= 8 & y < 60)] = NA
```

Answer (score 0):

@AbdurRohman's answer is good.

You could use

```r
md <- within(md,
   Children[Children >= 8 & Age <60] <- NA
)
```

for slightly clearer code. (You should definitely tell your instructor you got help on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Thanks, Ben follow-up question. I thought within was for adding new columns.  Does it not try adding a new column because there is already a column with that name?